# type object 'Enemy' has no attribute 'damage'

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
# attempt at a health system?

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self,name,health,damage):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage
    def attack(self):
        print(f"The {goblin.name} attacks! Causing {goblin.damage}  damage!")
        player.health -= Enemy.damage
        print(f"You have {player.health}")
        

goblin = Enemy("goblin",100,20)

class Player:
    def __init__(self,health,damage):
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage

player = Player(200,40)

goblin.attack()
```

```
error:

Traceback (most recent call last):File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\python stuff\project.py", line 10, in attackplayer.health -= Enemy.damage^^^^^^^^^^^^AttributeError: type object 'Enemy' has no attribute 'damage'
```

I just started programming and I don't know what this error means.

I wanted the terminal to display that the goblin I created caused damage, that is defined by its specific instance. The goblin should inflict 20 damage since that's what I wrote. I made a method under the "Enemy" class called "attack" where it should use the specific instance's name and damage and then write into the terminal what damage it does to the player. But I get this bug instead. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: The bug is you wrote `Enemy.damage` instead of `self.damage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use self instead

```
    def attack(self, player):
        print(f"The {self.name} attacks! Causing {self.damage} damage!")
        player.health -= self.damage
        print(f"You have {player.health} health left.")
```

Maybe like

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, health, damage):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage

    def attack(self, player):
        print(f"The {self.name} attacks! Causing {self.damage} damage!")
        player.health -= self.damage
        print(f"You have {player.health} health left.")

class Player:
    def __init__(self, health, damage):
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage

# Create instances
goblin = Enemy("goblin", 100, 20)
player = Player(200, 40)

# Perform attack
goblin.attack(player)
```